# Retrieve git branch content via api on Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I'm trying to list all files for a specific branch in a Azure Devops Repo via the API. Anyone knows if this is possible. I only found information about how to list the contents of a repo.
However, it's unclear from which branch the info is comming (I could derive it from the content), but that's not the idea...

I'm looking for a way to list the content of a branch on Azure Devops via the API

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list) API to retrieve/download the content of an Azure DevOps repository as follows:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items/items?path=/&versionDescriptor[versionOptions]=0&versionDescriptor[versionType]=0&versionDescriptor[version]={branchName}&resolveLfs=true&$format=zip&api-version=5.0&download=true
```

Replace the placeholders `{organization}`, `{project}`, `{repositoryId}` and `{branchName}` with your actual values.

P.S.: You can get the RepositoryId from the [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list) API.

Comment: I can confirm that the solution Bhargavi mentioned above works in an HTTP request.


I sent a request without versionDescriptor and branch settings, got a .zip file downloaded.
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path=/&$format=zip&download=true`

Also, I'm trying to figure out how to do this similar thing through SDK.

`item = git_client.get_item(repo.id, path="/abc/def/g.txt", download="true")`

the returned item has the correct response, but the download option does not work, might be some bug in SDK.